# Question about array of arrays initializing and resizing in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have come across this function in a book on c++ that I'm having trouble understanding exactly what's going on and why it all seems to be needed.

```
vector<vector<double>> StatisticsMean::GetResultsSoFar() const
{
    vector<vector<double> > Results(1);
    Results[0].resize(1);
    Results[0][0] = RunningSum / PathsDone;
    return Results;
}
```

From what I can tell we are initializing an array of arrays of size 1 in the first line, then why in the second line do we need to again resize the first array to size 1? In the third line we are simply assigning a value to the [0][0] element which makes sense. Can someone explain why all these operations are needed? Why wouldn't something like this work:

```
vector<vector<double>> StatisticsMean::GetResultsSoFar() const
{
    vector<vector<double> > Results;
    Results[0][0] = RunningSum / PathsDone;
    return Results;
}
```

Comment: You would be assigning a value to index 0 of the inner vector, while the size of the inner vector is 0. The assignment would be out of bounds, which is why it's necessary to initialize the subarray.

Comment: Something like this would work btw: `vector<vector<double> > Results{ { RunningSum / PathsDone } };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
vector<vector<double>> Results(1);
```

creates a vector of size 1 which has another vector as it's first element. But that other vector is size **zero**. This happens because the elements of `Results` are default constructed, and the default constructor for vector is a vector of size zero.

This code

```
vector<vector<double>> Results(1, vector<double>(1));
```

creates a vector of size 1 whose first element is also a vector of size 1.

Comment: Thank you very much, your second line of code is the how I was trying to rewrite it but couldn't quite get the syntax down.

vector<double> innerVector(1);

vector<vector<double>> Results(1,innerVector);

Results[0][0] = RunningSum /PathsDone;

Would something like this be just as efficient and "good" as the implementation in the book, or is there a reason to do it in the original way using resize()?

Comment: @Oscar That's a complicated question without a simple answer. The concern is to avoid copying vectors which is potentially inefficient (although a vector of size one is nothing to be too concerned about). My code creates a temporary vector `vector<double>(1)`, your version explicitly creates a vector `vector<double> innerVector(1);` and those vectors are copied to the `Results` vector whch sounds inefficient. The original code creates the inner vector *in place* so there is no copy. The catch is that compilers are allowed to skip this kind of copying (at least in the version I wrote).

Comment: @Oscar Someone more expert than me can probably give you the definitive answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

You might have known that `vector` is an array-like structure which has a certain `size`. When accessing `v[i]` where `i>=v.size()`, it is *undefined behavior* instead of automatically extending to `i`.

Therefore, to access `Result[0][0]`, it need to make sure `Result[0]` and `Result[0][0]` both exist beforehand.

Comment: A vector's `operator[]` does not throw an exception on an out-of-bound index. Its `at()` method does. Indexing with `operator[]` with an invalid index is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah you're right, it's UB actually. Thanks for correction. [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)

Answer (score 0):

```
 vector<vector<double>> StatisticsMean::GetResultsSoFar() const
{
    vector<vector<double> > Results(1);
    Results[0].resize(1);
    Results[0][0] = RunningSum / PathsDone;
    return Results;
}
```

`vector<vector<double> > Results(1)` created vector of vector with size 1. Inside vector still has size as 0. `Results.size()` will give you 1 but Results[0].size() will give you size as 0.

`Results[0]` returns the inside vector. `resize(1)` operation is creating vector of size 1 for inside vector. Please refer to John answer for creating vector of vector with predefined size.

Issue with below code is that both vector are of 0 size. If you will try to access 0 element in 0 size array it is undefined behavior ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) .

```
vector<vector<double>> StatisticsMean::GetResultsSoFar() const
{
    vector<vector<double> > Results;
    Results[0][0] = RunningSum / PathsDone;
    return Results;
}
```